# I have a ~ directory indicator installed now in the wrong place after docker runs

Tags: python, docker

I just put in a Dockerfile for some Python code I need to get into GKE.

```
 % ls
README.md       app_DEV.yaml        app_PROD.yaml       db.py           main.py         requirements.txt
```

I went through a couple of cycles of **docker build** before I got it done.

Then docker suggested a **docker scan** to look for vulnerabilities I tried it but left off the **.** after the command, which left me with an extra **~** home directory down in the hierarchy where I don't want it:

```
% ls
Dockerfile      README.md       app_DEV.yaml        app_PROD.yaml       db.py           main.py         requirements.txt    ~
```

What's the safest way to remove this? Python removing this directory entry? I don't want to goof and wipe my entire home directory.

Thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place the ~ in quotes:

```
rm -r "~"
```

This tells bash not to "expand" the tilda into your home directory.

If you want to test first, do:

```
echo ~
echo "~"
```

and you'll see that the first echo gives your home directory, and the second the tilda character. Let me know if you run into trouble!